# How do I configure SSHd to permit a single command, without giving full login access to the user?

Tags: ssh, remote, exec

I am looking for best way to call remote command over SSH. I create user 'rpcall', generate new certificate and fill authorized_keys. Secure it little bit more with

```
from="ip",no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ......
```

now user rpcall can't login to terminal

```
ssh -l rpc 192.168.12.1
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

but it is possible to run any command

```
ssh -l rpc 192.168.12.1 cat /etc/passwd
```

---

Is there any solution i can limit command execution only to one processing script?
For example /home/rpcall/bin/command.sh

I setuped bash shell for this user and using .bashrc force run processing script, but i don't know how to pass parameters from ssh call.

.bashrc for user rpcall

```
/home/rpcall/bin/command.sh $params1 $params2
exit
```

ssh call from other machine

```
ssh -l rpcall 192.168.12.1 "param1" "param2"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can restrict commands using the authorized_keys file.  Put `command="/home/rpcall/bin/command.sh"` before the key, in the authorized_keys file, and the user will only ever run that command when they connect.

Check the man page for authorized_keys, this is from that man page,

```
 command="command"
         Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used
         for authentication.  The command supplied by the user (if any) is
         ignored.  The command is run on a pty if the client requests a
         pty; otherwise it is run without a tty.  If an 8-bit clean chan-
         nel is required, one must not request a pty or should specify
         no-pty.  A quote may be included in the command by quoting it
         with a backslash.  This option might be useful to restrict cer-
         tain public keys to perform just a specific operation.  An exam-
         ple might be a key that permits remote backups but nothing else.
         Note that the client may specify TCP and/or X11 forwarding unless
         they are explicitly prohibited.  The command originally supplied
         by the client is available in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environ-
         ment variable.  Note that this option applies to shell, command
         or subsystem execution.
```

If you need more than one command, you need to basically set up several sets of keys and use different keys to give you different commands.

Edit: I just noticed, the original command is available in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable, so you could indeed handle that input using your own script, doing something clever.