# Can you have known_hosts and authorized_keys shell out to a command

Tags: ssh

Can you make ssh and sshd, instead of checking the ~/.ssh/known_hosts and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (respectively), invoke a command with the requested key as an argument, and accept the key only if the command accepts?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/407497/how-do-i-configure-sshd-to-permit-a-single-command-without-giving-full-login-ac

Answer (score 2):

I don't think sshd (running on the server) checks ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

However, see AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs configuration options.
Some code seems to be here: http://www.sysadmin.org.au/index.php/2012/12/authorizedkeyscommand/

But I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: In case of known_hosts I meant ssh.