# CentOS - make a user run a script on login and exit

Tags: centos, security, permissions, user-accounts

Is there a way to lock down an account to when it logs in, it runs a specific command/script and then exits after the action is completed, while keeping it locked out of performing any additional operations if it happens to break out of it's script/command?

Would prefer a native way of accomplishing this, but not necessary.

Comment: For remote SSH logins http://serverfault.com/questions/407497 may be of  interest.

Answer (score 0):

The old school way to handle this is `exec`ing your code from the user's `.profile`.  By using `exec` it will replace the login shell.  So if the user manages to break out there isn't a shell for them to escape back to.  When your login process exits Linux kills the session.